# How can I animate a TextBlock when a SelectionChanged() event of a ListBox is called?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0

In the code below, I want to start the animation when there's TextChanged() event of TextBlock is called. But when I try this code, I get an error...

"Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.EventTrigger.RoutedEvent'"

I am lost, could someone please assist me that how can I do this?

```
<StackPanel>
   <ListBox Name"lstSample" SelectionChanged="lstSample_SelectionChanged">
       <ListBox.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.SelectionChanged">
              <BeginStoryboard>
                  <BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
                      <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtSample" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:1.0">
                              <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                  <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Power="8"/>
                              </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                          </DoubleAnimation>
                      </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard.Storyboard>
              </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
       </ListBoxTriggers>
   </ListBox>

   <Border Name="brdrTextSampleLanguageOne" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}">
      <TextBlock 
             Text="This is sample text." 
             Name="txtSample" 
             TextAlignment="Right" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" />

    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be really easy using code, just create a property like:

```
 private string _textBlockText;
        public string textBlockText
        {
            get { return _textBlockText; }
            set
            {
                if (txtSample.Text != value)
                {
                    if (Storyboard1.GetCurrentState() != ClockState.Active)
                        Storyboard1.Begin();
                    txtSample.Text = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

Just use textBlockText property to update text in anywhere in your code and this should work like TextChanged event...  Note: Storyboard1 is the animation you desire to play on TextChanged Event.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. Where do I need to put Storyboard1 in XAML? Do you have any example of this somewhere?

Comment: e.g: 
<UserControl.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="StoryBoard1">
.
.your Storyboard
.

</Storyboard x:Name="CanvasHide">   
</UserControl.Resources>

Answer (score 0):

This will help you find the code below

```
<UserControl x:Class="WrapPanel.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
             xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="mystoryboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="txtSample"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                     From="0"
                                     To="1"
                                     Duration="0:0:1.0">
                        <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                            <PowerEase EasingMode="EaseIn"
                                       Power="8" />
                        </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <ListBox Name="lstSample"
                     SelectionChanged="lstSample_SelectionChanged">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption="Play"
                                                    Storyboard="{StaticResource mystoryboard}">

                        </ei:ControlStoryboardAction>

                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </ListBox>

            <Border Name="brdrTextSampleLanguageOne"
                    BorderThickness="0">
            <TextBlock Text="This is sample text."
                       Name="txtSample"
                       TextAlignment="Right"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" />

            </Border>

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Cheers!

Vinod

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't work for me. There's an error in XAML that (The attachable property "Triggers" was not found in "Interactions"), even though I have added System.Windows.Interactivity, Microsoft Expression Controls and Microsoft.Expression Interactions in the references, and also in the XAML namsespaces.

Comment: Do I need to replace "phone:PhoneApplicationPage" by "UserControl" ?

Comment: And yes, I have fully licensed version of Expression Blend 4 installed.

Comment: you need to add refreneces to Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity and and effects also

Comment: I don't find this resource anywhere on my pc

Comment: I have put the project alongwith dll required let me know if it works https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByoMrdMrOqXfdlhLaGxTLVFETHM

Comment: Alright, so it's "Microsoft.Expression.Prototyping.Interactivity" NOT "Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity" which you mentioned above. Perhaps my fault! :)

Comment: Sorry Vinod, I didn't try it, I spent time on it, but this recipe has many ingredients to bring together. The other answer is already working for me and simple to implement. Thanks very much for posting the answer, I will surely try it out and post my comments  but not now as I am very busy. Thanks again!